# R web scraping- Following "Read more" link and getting details using rvest

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

I am using rvest package to scrape information from a web page. I want to scrape first two page of the website http://www.ratemds.com/doctors/?page2=&specialty=family-gp&page=1

Below is my code. The problem i am facing is to scrape the comment portion. Where there is "Read more" i want to go to that link and scrape all the comments.

Can anyone give me any idea about how to do this?
I tried follow_link and jump_to but was not successful.

```
library(rvest)

hospital <- html("http://www.ratemds.com/doctors/?specialty=family-gp")

nxt_pg<- "&page=3"
nxt_pg1<- "?page2=&"
hospital_test1 <-paste0("http://www.ratemds.com/doctors/",nxt_pg1,"?specialty=family-gp",
                        nxt_pg,sep="") 
hospital_test1 <- html(hospital_test1)

web_crawler(x=hospital)

web_crawler <- function(x)

{
  Doctor_nm <- x %>%  
    html_nodes("h2 a") %>%
    html_text()
  Doctor_nm
  # return(Doctor_nm) 

  Comments <- x %>%
    html_nodes(".rating-comment") %>%
    html_text()
  Comments
  # return(Comments)
  return(list(Doctor_nm,Comments))
}

fd<-web_crawler(x=hospital)
df <- as.data.frame(fd)
colnames(df) <- c ("Doctors_nm","Comments")
fd1<-web_crawler(x=hospital_test1)
df1 <- as.data.frame(fd1)
colnames(df1) <- c ("Doctors_nm","Comments")

Final_data <- rbind(df,df1)
```

Comment: `help(html_session)` you need to be in a session context to use those effectively.

Comment: @hrbrmstr I tried using html_session but i am not sure how to use it. This is what i am getting                                                                          > s <- html_session("https://www.ratemds.com/doctors/?specialty=family-gp")
> s %>% follow_link("Read more")
Navigating to /doctor-ratings/42984/Dr-Leo-Lasalle-Montreal-QC.html#rating-2753543
<session> https://www.ratemds.com/doctor-ratings/42984/Dr-Leo-Lasalle-Montreal-QC.html
  Status: 200
  Type:   text/html; charset=utf-8
  Size:   98479

Comment: An alternative way is to get a list of all webpages associated with `read more` (see `view page sources` or `inspect`) and then parse these using `html`. or with each names of doctors and their ids, you can the unique url and then parse these accordingly.